# Is it possbile to run gitlab job from gitlab after jenkins job (or other external)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have pipeline on gitlab with some jobs. The last job is external and it is jenkins job. Is it possible to run one else gitlab job after successful ending this external job? If yes where should I define it in gitlab (gitlab-ci.yaml, settings)

Comment: Post you call Jenkins job, you'll have to execute a shell (or any type of script) which can hit Jenkins APIs to get the status of the job till it is successfully completed. Now, post this stage, you can call another job.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you. There is sth like post build actions that we can define in jenkins but for gitlab there are no many options. Mainly it is publish build status to gitlab. So the only option is as you said.